# scrollIntoView taking me to the top of page instead of bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, use-ref

I am using a common method to scroll to the bottom of a React component.

```
const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);
    
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
};

.....


<ul className="channel">
  {messages.map((message) => 
    <Fragment key={message.id}>
      message text
    </Fragment>
  )}
  <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
</ul>
```

But it is scrolling to the top of the component. I assume it's because I have a height and overflow:scroll set in the channel CSS class, because it works correctly without those settings, however, I need them to be there. How can I get this to scroll to the bottom? Can I somehow rewrite the scrollToBottom method to do the opposite of what its doing right now? TIA!

Comment: Do you need to scrolling to the end of the ul element?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with `scrollIntoView({block: "end"});`

Comment: Good suggestion but didnt work unfortunately :/

Comment: Could you prepare an example of your current progress?
I think it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-platform-8vgr2?file=/src/App.js:408-422